# Finding a quiet hotel in Madrid

Tags: hotels, spain, sleeping, madrid

I'm trying to find a quiet hotel in Madrid that's not too far out of the way. Normally, I'd just hit a hotel booking website, pick a few in the right geographical area and price range, and check the reviews. But here, I see a constant theme: noisy, walls too thin, activity outside all night, can hear the neighbours breeze… My search method isn't working.

How can I search for a hotel based on subjective criteria such as being suitably quiet for a light sleeper?

Comment: Good question! According to some studies, [Spain is one of the noisiest countries in the world](http://www.theolivepress.es/spain-news/2011/05/01/spanish-noise/), so it may not be easy. :) I've certainly noticed the "activity outside all night" part too when staying in Madrid.

Comment: Quiet hotel?  In Spain?  Don't you like wedding parties?

Answer (score 4):

In general:

- Try to go to hotels where the whole building is occuppied by the hotel
- Try to avoid big streets or roads nearby
- Obviously, do not choose hotels near night life areas
- Trust in hotels chains like Hilton, Western, etc.. they usually have stronger criterias when they build a hotel
- New hotels better than ancient buildings
- Hotels with fitted carpet are better when other guest arrive very late
- Ask for a room in the highest floors

In Madrid in particular, I can recommend the [hotel Husa Serrano Royal](http://www.hotelhusaserranoroyal.com/). I stay 2 years ago and I don't have any complaint about it, but the truth is that I can sleep anywhere :)

Answer (score 3):

My advice is: **find hotels *outside* inner Madrid** (that is roughly the area within the *M-30* motorway; a ring road).

***Las Tablas***, for example, is a new neighbourhood in the north, planned during the housing bubble, and with low occupancy. That means fairly quiet nights (and days). There seem to be [an NH](http://www.nh-hoteles.es/nh/es/hoteles/espana/madrid/nh-las-tablas.html?nhagentid=11009&nhsubagentid=110095220109&utm_source=google&utm_medium=maps&utm_campaign=googleplaces) and a Holiday Inn nearby. NB: I cannot recommend these two in particular (I haven't stayed); I just suspect they'll be quiet.

Around **Suanzes** (homonymous underground station; line 5, colour green) there is [an Ibis/Accor](http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-5100-ibis-budget-madrid-valentin-beato/index.shtml) that can't be expensive. I know those streets, and it can't be noisy at night...

Answer (score 1):

I have been working in Madrid for a while on business and I have sleep problems and I highly recommend the [Catalonia Atocha hotel](https://www.cataloniahotels.com/en/hotel/catalonia-atocha), it has very good prices and is a very quiet hotel and very close to the most emblematic places in Madrid.

Answer (score 0):

A [quick google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=madrid%20quiet%20hotels) reveals a couple of links.  The first one, from [Go Madrid](http://www.gomadrid.com/hotels/quiet-hotels.html), has this to say about the Hotel Conde Duque:

> The Hotel Conde Duque is really a quiet oasis in the bustling city of
>   Madrid. The hotel is located in the peaceful and landscaped square of
>   Plaza Conde Valle de Suchil close to the city centre, so instantly has
>   a more relaxed and inviting atmosphere than many of the other
>   available vacation spots in the city. It is ideally situated near the
>   metro so traveling to Madrid's "must see" attractions poses no problem
>   at all and can easily be done. The rooms here are very clean, with
>   well-appointed bathrooms, many of which have luxurious marble baths.
>   Breakfast is served promptly and is substantial, typical of a four
>   star venue. The setting of the hotel is quaint, overlooking a local
>   playground and park, which is filled every afternoon with children and
>   their families, giving the Conde Duque a real traditional, family
>   feel.

Which may fit your needs.  of course, you'd still need to check online reviews for this site, but it's a start - if a hotel is specifically listed on a separate list of allegedly quiet hotels.

Comment: Hello marketing speak. :)

Comment: Eithan, welcome to Travel.SE.  I wasn't quite sure what you were trying to do here - it doesn't entirely answer the question - they were wondering HOW to search for such hotels, not asking for a specific one, and definitely not for clear marketing talk.  So I googled your text, and found it was copied from http://www.gomadrid.com/hotels/quiet-hotels.html. We really do ask that you indicate where you took the text from with a link. What I suggest is editing your answer to say there's a site with quiet hotels, and include the link & details. As it stands, people are unlikely to vote it up ;)

Comment: I've updated the answer to give an idea of what I was thinking.  Let me know if that's ok and feel free to tailor it to your personal style if you wish, but let me know either way, and then I can delete these comments :)